# MediaWiki displays </dd>, </dl>, </dt>

Tags: html, mediawiki

I use **mediawiki** 1.19.1. I've created a bot that creates some pages containing the HTML tags `dd`, `dl` and `dt` (It's a well formed XML fragment)

```
<dl>
<dt>Title1</dt>
<dd>Definition2</dd>
<dt>Title2</dt>
<dd>Definition2</dd>
</dl>
```

It looks correct on http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Sandbox&oldid=508628268 but, my MW does not interpret the end-tag:

```
Title1</dt>

    Definition2</dd>

Title2</dt>

    Definition2</dd>
```

how can I fix this ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but can you use the [built in MediaWiki syntax for definition lists](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting#Text_formatting_markup)?

Comment: it's a nice suggestion but the HTML document is built by including different sources and then processed with XSLT: I cannot guess the number of spaces and the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Does the value of [$wgHtml5](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgHtml5) and [$wgWellFormedXml](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgWellFormedXml) influence how the code is parsed?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and ugly workaround is not to put `</dt>` and `</dd>` end tags.
My previous workaround was to use spans instead...